# How to process tiles of different sizes?

Tags: unity, sprites, tilemap

I have next problem.
Sprite sheet that I have has sprites of different sizes. I use 16 pixels per unit.

On the screen you can see a choosen tile and that it's height is 14 pixels. I can't resize it manually to 16 pixels as it would overlap a `car` sprite.

[image]

On the tile palette it results in next problem.
[image]

This gap is also in the game. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: The objects are probably not a problem. You could either pad them with transparent pixels so they fit the tilesize or just freely place them as separate sprites independent from the tilemap. But if your floor tiles don't fit your grid size, then that's  a problem. You either need to adjust your grid size so it fits your tiles, or you need to find/create/commission tiles that fit your desired grid size.

Comment: Hello Philipp.
I don't think that I can add transparent pixels to this particular sprite as there is no more space on the sprite sheet for it to resize. Maybe there is some other way to do it?
I did it for other sprites as I had more free space near them to use and add some pixels to their height and width.
All other tiles snap perfectly, so I don't think that there is an issue with the tilemap.
I would like to stick to the tilemap as otherwise I would need to fit all the sprites by myself.

Comment: Why not load the tileset into your preferred image editor and move them around if you need more space?

Comment: Sounds simple :)
I guess it should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like the tiles you have here are partially transparent tiles that are supposed to be placed on a separate layer with full tiles on the layer below them. That way they can be used to create transitions to all kinds of different floor types.

When you have tiles that are smaller or larger than the grid size, then their positioning within the grid is controlled by the **Pivot** setting of the sprite (visible in the lower right of your first screenshot). So you have to change the pivot pivot from "Center" to a custom value so that the position of the pivot point of the tile *would* be the center *if* the tile were actually 16x16. The pivot y-coordinate is measured from the bottom. But your tiles start at the top. So you need to:

1. Change the "Pivot" from "Center" to "Custom"
2. Set "Pivot Unit Mode" to "Pixels"
3. Set "Custom Pivot X" to `grid_width / 2`
4. Set "Custom Pivot Y" to `grid_height / 2 - (grid_height - tile_height)`. In your case, the grid_height is 16 and the tile_height is 14. So your pivot would be `16 / 2 - (16 - 14)` = **6**.

With the cars, you might also want to use a "Custom" pivot so you get full control over where exactly the sprites are placed in relation to the tile grid. In that case you can probably eyeball it and drag&drop the blue circle that marks the pivot to where you want the center of the tile to be.

Comment: Thank you, changing pivot helped.